# How to hide or adjust the display frequency of apex:chartLabel?

Tags: charts, visualforce-charting

Is there a way to hide or adjust the display frequency of apex:chartLabel? I tried the rendered attributes and it didn't work. Any helps would be appreciated.

**My Situation:**

This is my original problem. The Y-axis label is very messy. So I want to either hide it or adjust the display frequency of X Axis Label.

[image]

I tried to delete X-axis from my apex page.

```
<apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="score" title="Score" />
<!--<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="index" title="Opportunities">-->
```

The result is shown below. The line is also gone.

[image]

Then I came across apex:chartLabel and learned that it's used to edit chart axis's label. Chart label has a rendered attribute which, according to [this manual](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartLabel.htm), is:

> a Boolean value that specifies whether the chart label is rendered with the chart.

So I tried:

```
<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="index" title="Opportunities">
     <apex:chartLabel rendered="false"/>
</apex:axis>
```

Nothing showed up at all.

[image]

I thought I did something wrong so I tried setting the other attributes. I could change font size and rotate the label text. (But I couldn't get the color changing to work.) Is this a bug or the way I used these attribute is wrong?

```
<apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="index" title="Opportunities">
     <apex:chartLabel rotate ="90" font="16px Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#FF0000" />
</apex:axis>
```

[image]